# Susy grid changes container size when the font size changes -- how to work around this?

Tags: sass, susy-compass

I am using susy grids 1.0.9 and noticed something which has me confused.

I have two elements, ".page_1" and ".page_2", with identical settings -- spanning 10 columns each, padded on both sides.

I noticed an unexpected behavior: if I use `$container-style: static`, the container size starts changing depending on the font-size applied to said container.

If I change `font-size` to `1em` both containers are again the same size.

If I change '$container-style' to 'magic' both containers are the same size, too. This behavior takes place only with a font-size specified on the element when the `$container-style' is set to`static.`

What am I doing wrong?/Is there a workaround for this? Code below.

```
$total-columns: 12;
$column-width: 4em;
$gutter-width: 1em;
$grid-padding: $gutter-width;
$container-style: static;

#section_1 {
  background-color: #963;
  border: 4px solid green;

  .pages_wrapper {
    @include container;
  }

  .page {
    border:1px solid yellow;
    @include prefix(1);
    @include span-columns(10,12);
    @include suffix(1);

    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
  }

  .page_1 {
    font-size: 1em;
  }
  .page_2 {
    font-size: 1.25em;
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<section id="section_1">
  <section class="pages_wrapper">
    <section class="page_1 page">
      <h1>Page 1</h1>
    </section>
    <section class="page_2 page">
      <h1>Page 2</h1>
    </section>
  </section>
</section>
```

Screenshot showing the issue (Latest Chrome):

`$container-style:static;` , `.page_2 {font-size: 1em}` :
 [image: screenshot]

Comment: can you make any jsfiddle ?

Comment: Not sure how to include susy grids (a sass-based set of grid mixins) in a jsfiddle, so I used code and screenshots. Is such an inclusion possible possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The width of .page is calculated in em, because you set your column/gutter widths as ems (which are font-size based). Since you're giving .page_2 a larger font-size than .page_1 the width of the container will grow as well.

If you want to use the static layout you can change your column/gutter settings, or set a fixed container-width:

```
$container-width: 960px;
```

This will apply a fixed width of 960px on .pages_wrapper and the width of .page will get calculated in percent.

Alternatively, you could alter your HTML and apply font-size on an additional container inside the container that uses the span-column mixin:

```
<section id="section_1">
  <section class="pages_wrapper">
    <section class="page">
      <div class="page_1">
        <h1>Page 1</h1>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="page">
      <div class="page_2">
        <h1>Page 2</h1>
      </div>
    </section>
  </section>
</section>
```

Comment: So if I understand correctly, when container widths are font-size-based (ems), then applying a font-size directly to the container changes its width, too... because this overrides the current "global" font size which is the basis for `em`s. I worked around this by setting the font size on the `p` element similar to what you suggested. Thank you!